# Godot android export looks way different than in the IDE

Tags: android, godot, gdscript, shading

I am making a game for android using Godot. I have a scene that is completly dark(no light sources and a dark worldenvironment), in the IDE and on windows export it's pitch black darkness(as it is supposed to be) but on android every model is lit up by a non existant lightsource from the top-left.

[what it looks like on pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBgPw.png)
[what it looks like on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svk7T.png)

what could be causing this problem?

Comment: When you made the project, did you select GLES 3.0 or 2..0?  -  2.0 works better for mobile (performance wise), but lacks some of the shading features present in 3.0. Also, if you're using 3.0, I think Godot defaults to vertex lighting/shading when building for mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I was using a .dae file for my model, within godot i removed the light source that came with it but for some reason on phone it was still there. So to fix it i removed it within blender before export.